# ASP.NET MVC returning empty response

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**UPDATE** this appears to be a duplicate of [IISExpress serves empty pages when Visual Studio 2013 has the web project open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255824/iisexpress-serves-empty-pages-when-visual-studio-2013-has-the-web-project-open)

Question is whether there is any way to fix it other than disabling Browser Link altogether?  And why was it an issue in some projects but not others?

Original question:

I am getting a completely blank page from a simple controller/view inside an ASP.NET project.  There are response headers, but no response body and response `Content-Length` = 0.

My URL is `/Home` which calls `HomeController.Index`, and will forward to ~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml

```
class HomeController {
  public ActionResult Index() 
  {
     return View();
  }
}
```

Home/Index.cshtml:

```
@{
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Started view, layout {0}", Layout);
}

<h2>Index</h2>

Test view

@{System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Finished view");}
```

I see the output going to the console so I know routing is working and finding the right view.  I can also see no layout is in effect.

Where else should I be looking to see if something else in the pipeline is hijacking the view?   I don't see any exceptions or failures.  Where would I look for other things intercepting the request that could cause silent failure?

I am running in debug mode through Visual Studio Pro 2013.

Comment: Adding more specifics would be beneficial. Like the url you are pointing to, controller and action name, and view file name. Since MVC is convention based all of this matters,

Comment: Clarified, but I don't think it's a routing or naming issue.  The controller / action is getting called (verified by breakpoint) and the right .cshtml file is being accessed (breaking the cshtml page deliberately results in error).

Comment: That's indeed strange. Usually you can put a breakpoint in the .cshtml files. Have you tried that? What about looking at the html in the browser? Any way a style is hiding the content? I'm just throwing stuff out.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  breakpoint does trigger in index.cshtml.  HTML in browser is empty - response itself is empty, not a style issue.

Comment: Any luck? If you've got more information to provide post it. Other things I'd suggest is check Visual Studios callstack and output.

Comment: Showing some code may help, maybe your controller action and view?

Comment: Have you tried a different browser?  If it works in GC/FF but not IE there might be a reason (problem with _layout).  Can you start a completely new project/site using MVC template and does that work?   Does it work for anyone else (ie just not for you)?  You say 'static text is not returned' - better show us the content of index.cshtml - reduce this to the bare minimum `<h1>test</h1>` and see what you get.

Comment: what happens if you throw an exception in the view?